# Set relationship property in a range in Neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, relationship, shortest-path

I follow this [Link](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/graph-updates/graph-generators/) to use a graph generator  to create a graph scaling to +10000 nodes and to execute the shortest path algorithm between two nodes.

How can I set the relationship property for all the nodes to be in a specific range?

This [Link](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/alpha-algorithms/graph-generation/#graph-generation-distribution) provides more options, but I don't know how to use it. Any help?

Update: I do the as follow:

```
CALL gds.beta.graph.generate('test', 10, 3, 
{
  relationshipDistribution: 'random',
  relationshipProperty: {
                        name:'myProperty',
                        type: 'RANDOM',
                        min : 40.0,
                        max : 80.0
                        }
})
YIELD name, nodes, relationships, generateMillis, relationshipSeed, averageDegree, relationshipDistribution, relationshipProperty
```

The following error occurs:

```
Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed
Failed to invoke procedure `gds.beta.graph.generate`: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0):

my best guess

```
relationshipProperty: {
                        name:'myProperty',
                        type: 'RANDOM',
                        min : 40.0,
                        max : 80.0
                      }
```

Comment: I updated the question pls give me any idea about the error.

Comment: as per the documentation on the link you provided, I would try

relationDistribution:'RANDOM'

Comment: Sorry but It doesn't work. please help me. Try it please.

Comment: Can I create the graph using `CALL apoc.generate.er(10,5,'TestLabel', 'TEST_REL_TYPE');` then set the relationship property for all the edges using one Cypher?

Comment: yes, there is no reason why you could not do it. it would give you even more control.